# Java storage and management of access tokens

Tags: java, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm developing a REST service and now want to implement token authentication (OAuth2). Services are divided into two parts:

1. The authorization server. The client contacts the server and receives an access token. The token will be stored for some time in the database.
2. Server resources (use DropWizard framework). The client sends a request to + access token to the server. The resources server sends authorization server access token for verification and receives the necessary data for processing the client request. If all is well сlient receives a response to the request.

The **question** concerns the authorization server. Need an automatic control of the lifetime of the token, token write to the database with the specified structure, etc. Is there a ready library/framework for management access tokens? Or similar usually developed manually?

P.S. Ready to listen to any(!) comments on the architecture of the service.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You don't need a token database and don't have to contact the authorization server from the protected resource if you use self-contained tokens. See e.g. JSON Web Tokens (JWT) with signature (JWS). There's a problem though not using a database: you cannot revoke tokens.

Comment: Zólyomi István, thank you very much for the advice. I will implement authorization in my service like you tell. Later, I shall write here the implementation of this.